# Javascript/JQuery/Output Different output between promise and await when calling endpoint using JQUERY.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I'm getting some mock data from a mock endpoint, using JQuery and promises.

Just for the sake of it, I want to try and make it work with async/await.

I think I managed to find some code that works, although, I don't get the same output ( in chrome browser) in the console.

Here are the two pieces of code :

```
import $ from 'jquery';

let myPromise = $.get("http://5e2f41529c29c900145db22d.mockapi.io/test/users");

myPromise
    .then(
        (data) => {
            console.log('Success promises: ', data);
        }
    )
    .catch(
        (error) => {
            console.log('Error : ', error.responseText);
        }
    );
```

and

```
// same as above but with async/await

import $ from 'jquery';


let getUsersFromEndPoint = async function (){
    try {
        let users = await $.get("http://5e2f41529c29c900145db22d.mockapi.io/test/users");
        console.log('Success Async: ' + users);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error : ', error.responseText);
    }
};

getUsersFromEndPoint();
```

And they output : 
[image: output]

I'm not sure what the difference is.
Does anyone know why i get a different output ? and what they both "mean" ?

Thank you !

Comment: Change `+` to `,` in the async version.

Comment: same thing, you are just treating the objects as strings with the '+' in console.log('Success Async: ' + users);

Comment: wow, not too bright aha.. Thank you so much guys !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the promise-based code and the `async`/`await` are correct, and do the same thing, except a small (and therefore hard-to-spot) difference.

The promise-based version's logger code:

```
console.log('Success promises: ', data);
```

...logs the result as you expect.

However, in the async function, the `console.log` contains a `+` operator, that casts its second operand (the data) into a string, so all objects get transformed into `"[object Object]"`:

```
console.log('Success Async: ' + users);
```

Pass data as the second argument of `console.log` (as you've done with the promise version), and you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanation !